# WebAPI using BreezeJS throws an error as soon as I use $skip

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

I have a working WebAPI (v2) which utilizes the awesome BreezeJS product.  I am attempting to add paging capabilities, but as soon as I include $skip in the URL as a parameter, the WebAPI generates this error:

```
{
  $id: "1",
  $type: "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
  Message: "An error has occurred."
}
```

Debugging the API does not give me any additional information, since it doesn't crash.

The parameters I'm passing are:  http://www.example.com/api/Test/Designs?$skip=5&$top=5&$inlinecount=allpages&

If I call it without the $skip parameter, it works fine.  The other "$" params seem to work just fine, as I can call:

http://www.example.com/api/Test/Designs?$top=3

and it works as expected.

I have verified that I'm not using any BreezeQueryable attributes or anything, so $skip should be allowed.

Additional setup info if it helps:

- SQL Server Express v2012
- Breeze on the server side is v1.5.0.0
- Entity Framework v6
- Microsoft.Data.OData is v5.6

Is there something else I need to have enabled in order to utilize paging?  Or is there a way I can find the true cause of this error?  I can provide a working URL if requested.

Thank you.

Comment: Correct. You must add an `.orderby` clause when you use a `.skip` clause. You'll see this in action in [the breeze query documentation](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#Paging). This is an EF constraint, not a Breeze constraint.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy and Ward - that was the solution.  Jeremy, submit an answer please so you can get credit for getting me the answer first.  (Thank you too Ward - you're always a huge help in the community)

Comment: Ward - is it possible for Breeze server-side to watch for a situation like this and throw and error before EF gets ahold of it?  At least then we could show a meaningful error.  Thoughts on an enhancement request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sort is required to use `skip`:

From the [breeze docs](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#Paging):

```
// Skip the first 10 Products and return the rest
// Note that the  '.orderBy' clause is necessary to use '.skip'
// This is required by many server-side data service implementations
var query3 = EntityQuery.from('Products')
    .orderBy('ProductName')
    .skip(10);
```